# Bootstrap popover tooltips within DHTMLX Gantt

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover, dhtmlx

I'm using [DHTMLX Gantt](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/index.html) within an AngularJS application. I display some tooltips with the help of [Bootstrap's popover for AngularJS](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) (ui.bootstrap.popover). Furthermore I want so show some of those tooltips in my Gantt on certain HTML-Elements. However, they won't show up. So I'm wondering whether this is actually possible and if so, could someone help me to conduct this?

Thank you already in advance for your help!

Comment: I've solved it by using the pure JavaScript version of Bootstrap popover. For more information please see my own response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've solved the problem during the meanwhile. I think the problem was, that the elements within the Gantt are added dynamically and thus the popover can't be initialized. Hence I just took the [pure JavaScript version of the Bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). When using this one, I could use the element attributes and then I initialized the popovers in "onGanttRender". This works for me now properly.